# Phonegap/Cordova pre populated SQLite data retrieve too slow

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

The Phonegap/Cordova project using https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin for using SQLite. There is minor changes made in `MainViewController.m` to use pre-populated databse (however it might not effect the problem).

The database detecting very well here is the databaase detecting **code**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "database.db"});
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

    function queryDB(tx) {
        console.log("started");
        tx.executeSql("select * from user_info", [], function(tx, res) {
            console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length);
        });
    }

    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL : "+err.message);
    }
}
```

Result

```
res.rows.length: 1
```

Here is the retrieving data code which takes about **10 sec** to show result :(

```
function callMe (argument) {
    db.transaction(buttonqueryDB, buttonerrorCB);
    function buttonqueryDB(transaction) {
        console.log("going to query");
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM home_word', [], function(transaction, result) {
            console.log("total itemes " + result.rows.length);
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    console.log("this result : " +row.word);
                }
            }

        });
    }
    function buttonerrorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL : "+err.message);
    }
}
```

The **going to query** shows quickly and query result display takes about **10sec**

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use LocalStorage? Which is near native performance.

Comment: I don't think Sqlite is slow. If you are testing in the **android emulator** than it will be quite slow compared to testing in actual Android device. I have retrieved more than 1000 rows in less than a second. My laptop configuration is 8GB of RAM and i5 3rd Gen processor still the Android emulator takes almost 15 to 20 sec just to load the APK files. Try the App in the actual device, it should run quite fast.

Comment: @James Wong I think **LocalStorage** has size limit. The pre-populated database size I am using is about 21MB

Comment: @frank The database size I am using is **21MB** and even pre-populated copying doesn't take time. The result above query is searching from 1,25,2100 rows. Testing on iOS emulator takes about **5sec** and testing on iPhone takes **10sec** :(

Comment: Ok. Your rows are on the higher side. Have you tried Indexing your tables. I can see that you are doing a `select *` and then you are just processing only 10 rows `(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. You can try to preload the data when the App is initializing in the background. Even though that may not decrease the time, but it may improve the App experience from the user perspective.

Comment: @frank I am facing same problem. I have made primary key in each table but still it is slow on android it is taking almost *60 sec. How to preload data ? Can you give me any reference ?

Comment: @frank Could give any reference please

Comment: I have same problem with you. I use chrome 40 to test, os is mac os 10.10. Do you have find the answer? I'm not sure use  `ngStorage`  will fix this problem.